# Replace Paid Shipping Method With Free Shipping Method WooCommerce

Tags: filters, plugins

If I have a store that offers flat rate shipping of `$10` and free shipping for orders over $100 and a customer orders over `$100` it doesn't make much sense for them to have to see both `free shipping` and `flat rate shipping` on the checkout page. Why would a user even choose `flat rate shipping`?

How can I use a filter to detect if `free shipping` is available, filter the `flat rate shipping` label so it says something like `flat rate shipping (free)`, and then disable the `free shipping` method.

The end result is that if a user orders less than `$100` they see `flat rate shipping $10` and if they order over `$100` they see `flat rate shipping (free!)`.

Answer (score 0):

I got no clue of WooCommerce, but from a brief look at their [Action and Filter Reference](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/), I can see various results for `*shipping*`.

Most of them seem to be located in a file named `form-shipping.php`:

### Template Hooks: Actions

- `woocommerce_before_checkout_shipping_form`
- `woocommerce_after_checkout_shipping_form`
- `woocommerce_before_shipping_calculator`
- `woocommerce_after_shipping_calculator`
- `woocommerce_cart_totals_after_shipping`
- `woocommerce_checkout_shipping`
- `woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping`
- `woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping`

### Template Hooks: Filters

- `woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label`
- `woocommerce_shiptobilling_default`
- `woocommerce_shipping_calculator_enable_city`
- `woocommerce_shipping_calculator_enable_postcode`

### Class Hooks: Actions

- `woocommerce_calculated_shipping`
- `woocommerce_load_shipping_methods`
- `woocommerce_shipping_init`
- `woocommerce_shipping_method_chosen`

### Class Hooks: Filters

- `woocommerce_available_shipping_methods`
- `woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping`
- `woocommerce_cart_ready_to_calc_shipping`
- `woocommerce_cart_shipping_packages`
- `woocommerce_countries_shipping_to_prefix`
- `woocommerce_order_amount_shipping`
- `woocommerce_order_amount_shipping_tax`
- `woocommerce_order_shipping_method`
- `woocommerce_order_shipping_to_display`
- `woocommerce_shipping_.$this->id._is_available`
- `woocommerce_shipping_calculator_enable_city`
- `woocommerce_shipping_calculator_enable_postcode`
- `woocommerce_shipping_chosen_method`
- `woocommerce_shipping_fields`
- `woocommerce_shipping_method_supports`
- `woocommerce_shipping_method_title`
- `woocommerce_shipping_methods`

I guess one of those is the one you're searching for. Maybe there's even a combination of them that you can use to even improve your idea (see that *endless* list as ... some kind of inspiration).

Anyway, you'll have to write a lot of test callbacks for all that filters until you got the right one. The WooCommerce documentation seems nothing aside from this endless list with the file name (w/o folder). So if you or someone else wants to deal with *that*: Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `woocommerce_available_shipping_methods` filter to do that. NB: if you have Role Based Shipping plugin you might find that it removes the Free Shipping option under some circumstances; this code puts it back if shopper has a coupon for Free Shipping.

```
/**
* if Free Shipping method is available, reduce to just Free Shipping
* @param array $available_methods
* @return array
*/
add_filter('woocommerce_available_shipping_methods', function($available_methods) {
    global $woocommerce;

    // check for coupon with Free Shipping
    if (wpse_114581_has_coupon_free_shipping()) {
        // ensure that Free Shipping is in the list of available methods (again -- Role Based Methods may strip Free Shipping for Guests)
        if (!isset($available_methods['free_shipping'])) {
            $available_methods['free_shipping'] = new WC_Shipping_Rate('free_shipping', 'Free Shipping', 0, array(), '');
        }
    }

    // if both Free Shipping and another method, reduce to just free shipping
    if (isset($available_methods['free_shipping']) && count($available_methods) > 1) {
        $available_methods = array('free_shipping' => $available_methods['free_shipping']);

        // change title on Free Shipping method
        $available_methods['free_shipping']->method_title = 'flat rate shipping (free!)';
    }

    return $available_methods;
});

/**
* check for coupon with free shipping
* @return bool
*/
function wpse_114581_has_coupon_free_shipping() {
    global $woocommerce;

    foreach ($woocommerce->cart->applied_coupons as $code) {
        $coupon = new WC_Coupon($code);
        if ($coupon->is_valid() === true) {
            if ($coupon->enable_free_shipping()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Not counter downvoting that, but closures? Have fun removing that.

Comment: Closures are a bad idea for published plugins and themes, but shouldn't be a problem for website-specific customisations. Horses for courses :)

Comment: Horses? But yeah, sure. Closures are fine. For those who don't need debugging and overriding and have PHP 5.3+

Comment: '"woocommerce_available_shipping_methods" filter is deprecated from WooCommerce 2.1.'